# Facebook access_token error in Blackberry

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, blackberry

In my Blackberry app using phonegap, I have Facebook share feature and I am doing this using phonegap's childbrowser. After I login to Facebook, access_token is to be requeted. For this I am using the following code :

```
$.ajax({
            url:'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='+my_client_id+'&client_secret='+my_secret+'&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data, status){
                alert(22);
                // We store our token in a localStorage Item called facebook_token
                localStorage.setItem(facebook_token, data.split("=")[1]);
                                                    window.plugins.childBrowser.close();

                app.init();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("fail"+error['message']);
                window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
            }
        });
```

But the control is not going inside the success section instead it is going inside error section. What may be the problem. When I try to find the error using "`alert("fail"+error['message']);`", it is coming as undefined. Please help me to resolve this.